# kivy button not perfect square when window is resized

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have created a ScrollView with a GridLayout that has a bunch of buttons. my issue is that I cant get the buttons to be a perfect square when changing the window size.

.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class LogInScreen(Screen):
    pass
class EmployeeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class MyLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y = (None)
        self.bind(minimum_height = self.setter('height'))



class Manager(ScreenManager):
    login_screen = ObjectProperty(None)
    employee_screen = ObjectProperty(None)


class CptApp(App):
    icon = 'Images\login\cptlogo.png'
    title = 'CPT'
    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__=='__main__':
    CptApp().run()
enter code here
```

.kv file:

```
#: import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<Manager>:
id: screen_manager

login_screen: login_screen
employee_screen: employee_screen


LogInScreen:
    id: login_screen
    name: 'login'
    manager: screen_manager

    FloatLayout:
        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'lr-tb'
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Image:
                size_hint_y: .1
                source: 'Images\login\cptbanner.jpg'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True

            Image: 
                source: 'Images\login\HD7Brw.jpg'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False

    Label:
        size_hint_y: .05
        size_hint_x: .5
        pos_hint: {"x": .25, "y": .7}
        markup: True
        text: '[i][b][color=#000000]USER NAME[/color][/b][/i]'

    TextInput:
        id: 'username_input'
        multiline: False
        size_hint_x: .4
        size_hint_y: .05
        pos_hint: {"x": .3, "y": .65}

    Label:
        size_hint_y: .05
        size_hint_x: .5
        markup: True
        text: '[i][b][color=#000000]PASSWORD[/color][/b][/i]'
        pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': .5}

    TextInput:
        id: 'password_input'
        multiline: False
        password: True
        size_hint_x: .4
        size_hint_y: .05
        pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .45}

    Image:
        source: 'Images/login/loginbutton.png'
        size_hint_x: .25
        size_hint_y: .1
        pos_hint: {'x': .375, 'y': .25}

    Button:
        id: 'login_button'
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        markup: True
        text: '[i][b][color=#000000]LOGIN[/color][/b][/i]'
        size_hint_x: .25
        size_hint_y: .1
        pos_hint: {'x': .375, 'y': .25} 
        on_release: screen_manager.current = 'employeescreen'

EmployeeScreen:
    id: employee_screen
    name: 'employeescreen'
    manager: screen_manager

    StackLayout:
        orientation: 'lr-tb'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Image:
            size_hint_y: .1
            source: 'Images\login\cptbanner.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: True

        ScrollView:
            size: (Window.width, Window.height)

            MyLayout:
                cols: 2                 
                height: self.minimum_height
                pos: root.pos

                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'    
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'
                Button:
                    height: 40
                    size_hint_y: None
                    text: 'TEST'                    

enter code here
```

I want the height of the buttons to be the same as whatever the width is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply set the width to the same constant like so:

```
Button:
   height: 40
   size_hint_y: None
   width: 40
   size_hint_x: None
   text: 'TEST'
```

This produces perfect squares, but I guess this isn't what you want.

[image: this]

Another very simple thing is to set the button's height to be the same as it's width (literally):

```
Button:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.width
    text: 'TEST'
```

Which produces a nice result.

[image: result].

And, when resized:

[image: resized]

Perfect squares still.

Comment: setting the buttons height to be the same as its width is not doing it for me. did you change anything else other than adding size_hint_y: None and height: self.width?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, The only thing I changed is what I wrote in my answer. Here's the whole .kv code, tell me if it works: https://pastebin.com/KbtrX1K9

Comment: my code looks exactly like your and still wont work. what you are doing is exactly what I want. It just wont work for me for some reason.

Comment: self.width was not working, I tried self.parent.width and that worked. thank you for your time, you been very helpful.

Comment: also had to divide by 2. else will get a button that's exactly the height of the parent width. because I will be having the buttons in pairs.